# In WP7, data is not saved immediately after writing to IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I encountered this problem while polishing my WP7 application.

Though I follow Microsoft's guidelines to store game state when it's being deactivated, I'd also like to save some data in runtime.

The reason for this is that when the battery is removed from device, no deactivation / closing callbacks are triggered.

The problem with this comes when the user walks through the game and accidentally removes the battery from her device - all game progress is lost.

That's why I do save game state at some intermediate checkpoints, but I have noticed that data is not stored immediately. This is my "save" function:

```
    public void SaveAppModelToIsolatedStorage()
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(APPMODEL_DATAFILE,
                                                          FileMode.Create,
                                                          FileAccess.Write,
                                                          store))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppModel));

            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, AppModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cant serialize AppModel:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

After it's been called, if I remove the battery within a number of seconds (not sure how many but always less than 30), the application ends up with lost game progress. If I wait before removing battery, the data would be saved successfully. This behavior is observed on various WP7 phones.

I also tried serialization into a string buffer and then writing that string buffer to the file by calling `stream.Write()`, but the result is the same. Also, `stream.Flush()` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is this behavior a platform feature?

Is it fine in terms of Microsoft certification for Marketplace apps?

Or is there a way to save data immediately?

Comment: "Is it fine in terms of Microsoft certification for Marketplace apps" -> You're not supposed to handle this case, so don't worry about certification.

Comment: You say "After it's been called" - are you checking to see if the method has actually finished executing? It may not be completing as quickly as you think.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `stream.Close` when you need flush your data.

Also, try calling `stream.Flush(true);`

Comment: The Dispose on the stream should have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I tried both explicitly with no effect. And 'using' statement ensures that stream.Dispose() is called implicitly. And as per MSDN, disposing the IsolatedStorageFileStream will close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

This may be interesting regarding performance of Isolated Storage : forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/71708/71708.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm ok with the slow performance of Isolated Storage. However, it would be better that save process is done synchronously or at least fire callback when it is completed. With my current implementation it does neither of these.